# Problem with inserting data into the database MySQL syntax error

Tags: mysql, lua

I got a syntax error that I am unable to resolve. 
I am trying to insert data into a MySQL Database using mysql-async 
and I am receiving the error that I have a syntax error, though I 
am unable to find what the problem is. This is the error that I receive.

[image]

This is how the database table structure looks like.
[image]

And on the following pictures I am handling the data itself.
Normally I need to add in more information, but for debugging
purposes I have uncommented everything and found the problem
started at the Group entry.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am using this exact same method for all other data 
insertions with no errors or problems, so I am not 
seeing anything obvious that I am doing wrong or 
different. By now I looked so much at it, that I am 
probably overlooking the error. I hope you guys find
whatever I am doing wrong.

Many thanks in advance and have a great weekend!

Comment: `GROUP` is a reserved word, you need to put it in backticks.

Comment: Okey I am facepalming myself so hard right now, Ill probably feel it next week still. Especially as on my first initial write I now remember I had the same problem and called it Groups haha. Many thanks for your time Barmar it resolved my problems, have a great weekend!